# Groovy/Grails Tools Suite (GGTS) code-assist in GSP pages for model objects

Tags: grails, gsp, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, code-assist

I am a newbie in Grails, and still learning.

I have the following code for the model:

```
class Book {

    static constraints = {

    }

    String title
    String author
}
```

and controller:

```
class KillController {

    def index() { render "kill world"  }

    def view() {
        def book = new Book( author: "Mike", title: "nuff sed")
        [ model: book ]
    }
}
```

And for `view.gsp`, I have the following:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Author: ${ model.author }<br />
        Title : ${ model.title }
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything is working, and the correct output is produced.  However, in the GSP editor, when I type `${ model. }`, I don't get any proposals from code-assist.  Pressing ctrl+space after typing the dot does not help.

Pressing Ctrl+space inside `${ }` works though, and it correctly recognizes `model` as a `Book` object.

Is code assist for models not yet supported in the GSP editor?  Thanks! :D

Comment: Richard, I have no idea about Eclipse, but I know for sure that it works in IntelliJ. So if Eclipse doesn't support it, maybe IntelliJ (the Ultimate, paid, version) might prove to be of more help.

Comment: Thanks!  I want to stick to Eclipse, being free, for the meantime...:D  It's either a bug or it's not yet supported.

I remember when working with PHP in Eclipse, you sometimes would have to provide hints to the IDE with something like `/* @var $model Book */`.  I figured since both are dynamic languages, there might be a similar workaround in GGTS.  Although, GGTS does recognize the type of `model` in the GSP code, so I'm quite hopeful that if it's not a bug, it'll be supported someday :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug.  It should be working and it does in many other situations.  When I try it, I do see that an exception is being thrown:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.OperationCanceledException
at org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.codeassist.processors.GroovyProposalTypeSearchRequestor.checkCancel(GroovyProposalTypeSearchRequestor.java:356)
at org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.codeassist.processors.GroovyProposalTypeSearchRequestor.processAcceptedPackages(GroovyProposalTypeSearchRequestor.java:618)
at org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.codeassist.processors.PackageCompletionProcessor.generateProposals(PackageCompletionProcessor.java:56)
at org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.codeassist.requestor.GroovyCompletionProposalComputer.computeCompletionProposals(GroovyCompletionProposalComputer.java:162)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.editor.gsp.adapter.CodeCompletionDelegate.codeComplete(CodeCompletionDelegate.java:71)
at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.model.GroovyCompilationUnit.codeComplete(GroovyCompilationUnit.java:598)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.codeComplete(CompilationUnit.java:359)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui.internal.contentassist.JSPJavaCompletionProposalComputer.computeJavaCompletionProposals(JSPJavaCompletionProposalComputer.java:237)
at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui.internal.contentassist.JSPJavaCompletionProposalComputer.computeCompletionProposals(JSPJavaCompletionProposalComputer.java:114)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalComputerDescriptor.computeCompletionProposals(CompletionProposalComputerDescriptor.java:284)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.contentassist.CompletionProposalCategory.computeCompletionProposals(CompletionProposalCategory.java:290)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.contentassist.StructuredContentAssistProcessor.collectProposals(StructuredContentAssistProcessor.java:475)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.contentassist.StructuredContentAssistProcessor.computeCompletionProposals(StructuredContentAssistProcessor.java:254)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.contentassist.CompoundContentAssistProcessor.computeCompletionProposals(CompoundContentAssistProcessor.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant.computeCompletionProposals(ContentAssistant.java:1839)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.computeProposals(CompletionProposalPopup.java:566)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.access$16(CompletionProposalPopup.java:563)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup$2.run(CompletionProposalPopup.java:498)
...
```

I'll have to see what is going on here.

---

UPDATE:

Raised this issue: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3337

Found the problem and pushed a fix.  Will be available in next snapshot build.